# Can rake stats be obtained in json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am planning to use the stats for my rails app for analysis.

I obtained the stats using

```
rake stats
```

All I obtained is a ascii formatted table. Is there a way to get this in JSON?

Answer (score 2):

Super-hacky and not in any way clever, but, here's how to turn a `|` separated table into json.

```
lines = `rake stats`.split("\n").collect{|l| l.split("|").collect(&:strip).reject(&:blank?)}.select{|l| l.size > 1}
hashes = []
headers = lines.shift
lines.each do |line|
  hash = {}
  headers.each_with_index do |header,i|
    hash[header] = line[i]
  end
  hashes << hash
end
hashes.to_json
```